# Can you reset World.frameCount in Code.org JS (Game Lab)?

Tags: javascript, random, game-development, procedural-generation, code.org

This question is for a game I am working on in the Game Lab in Code.org. The game in question will be like a skydiving game, where obstacles spawn at random intervals (between 1000 and 3000 ms). Here is the code:

```js
World.frameRate = 10;
var rects = createGroup();
var timeout = Math.round(randomNumber(800, 3000) / 100) * 100;

function draw() {
  background("white");
  drawSprites();
  if (World.frameCount === Math.round(randomNumber(1000, 3000) / 100) * 100) {
    World.frameCount = 0;
    creation();
  }
}

function creation() {
  var obstacle = createSprite(randomNumber(100, 300), 200, 50, 20);
  obstacle.velocityY = -2;
}
/*
setInterval(function() {
  creation();
}, Math.round(randomNumber(800,3000)/100)*100);
*/
```

In order to create the spawning mechanism, I tried using the `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` functions, but with those two, on the first execution, it creates a random number, and from there, continues to spawn objects at the same interval. I couldn't find any workarounds around this, so I moved on to `World.frameCount`. This concept works, however, due to the `===` operator, obstacles will only spawn between 1 and 3 seconds, after 3 seconds, objects will not be able to spawn. In order to fix this, I added in line 9 (`World.frameCount = 0;`). When run, this produces an error:

```
ERROR: Line: 9: TypeError: Cannot set property frameCount of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

I understand that this error is because you cannot alter the value of `World.frameCount`. Are there any workarounds to this? I would also appreciate any suggestions on other ways this can be done.

Here's the link to the Code.org project: [Skydive v1.0](https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/k_DwPLd1UfXQQOX17if_4iEP5SWyBSpnwOjEd365tVY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to set `World.frameCount`. If you want to spawn objects at a variable interval, use this:

```js
(function timeoutHandler() {
  creation();
  setTimeout(timeoutHandler, randomNumber(800,3000)/100)*100);
})();
```

Comment: So this goes outside of the draw() function, right?

Comment: Yes, outside the `draw()` function.